# Worpdress WYSIWYG not adding custom format classes to paragraph

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have an issue on a WYSIWYG editor using custom formats.
When I select a paragraph to add a custom format the editor doesn't add the class that I need.
I checked that the styles are working on my editor, if I add the class manually automatically gets the correct CSS styles.
I have no errors when using the dropdown menu.

This is my code

```
function mce_set_styles_dropdown_options($settings)
{
    $styleFormats = [
        [
            'title' => __('Heading 1'),
            'inline' => 'p',
            'classes' => 'h1',
        ],
        [
            'title' => __('Heading 2'),
            'inline' => 'p',
            'classes' => 'h2',
        ],
        [
            'title' => __('Heading 3'),
            'inline' => 'p',
            'classes' => 'h3',
        ],

    ];

    $settings['style_formats_merge'] = false;
    $settings['style_formats'] = json_encode($styleFormats);

    return $settings;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_set_styles_dropdown_options');


function mce_load_content_css($settings)
{
    $adminCss = getHashedAsset('/app.css');

    $settings['content_css'] = empty($settings['content_css'])
        ? $adminCss
        : $settings['content_css'] . ',' . $adminCss;

    return $settings;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_load_content_css');
```

This is my editor with the custom formats select with the correct styles
[image: WYSIWYG EDITOR]